# using a rails app with the most recent posts on top

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am making a help wanted type app, and I would like the app to list the jobs with the most recent posts at top, and older ones being pushed down each time a newer job is posted. So far I am displaying the posts thusly:

```
<% if @jobs.any? %>
<ul>
  <% @jobs.each do |job| %>
  <li><%= link_to job.description, job_path(job) %></li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
<% else %>
<p>There are no odd jobs yet.</p>
<% end %>
```

any suggestions?

Comment: You can use `order` and specify which column of the `jobs` table use for ordering them (created_at perhaps).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your controller file, (which I'm guessing is in the file jobs_controller.rb), under the index action, you can dictate an order:

```
def index
  @jobs = Job.order(created_at: :desc)
end
```

This will order your jobs by creation date. You can change the `created_at` to any other attribute on your job.

You can learn more about order [here](https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/QueryMethods/order).

Comment: worked like a charm. except i think you meant in the controller cleverly named  jobs_controller.rb